# Im using a Chromebook 11 3180 and i want to make it so my touchpad stops twitching

Tags: touchpad, chromebook

Its a chromebook 11 3180. Its also twitchy.

What im trying to say is that my mouse pointer keeps twitching, and sometimes does not respond at all even when I do "press esc multiple times and then drumroll on the touchpad"... And its more than just one chromebook (I'm using this for school); more than 60% of the chromebooks we have have this problem... I'm basically trying to "fix" the Chromebooks that have this problem.

And if you *do* happen to find the answer, could you email me at munerunnr51@gmail.com plz? thx.

Comment: If the Chromebook does not have an alternate mouse input (like a trackpoint) - it probably does not, then you very most likely cannot disable the touchpad.  See if a new driver is available for it.

Comment: Okay, but i dont have a mouse usb extension, nor a bluetooth mouse to use... its just me, the chromebook, and my usb file drive.

Comment: The manufacturers need to know that beginners can use the on-board mouse when they need support. So it remains that it cannot be disabled.

Comment: Does it do this even just running on battery? If it does it only when connected to mains, it's likely a mains issue bad rectifier somewhere]… unless it does it when connected to any mains, anywhere, in which case I'd be looking into sending it back as faulty.